# Using dd is overwriting a part from a device and not the whole device?

Tags: gparted, format

I have a problem In my USB stick, it's 32GB but it's showing me inside Gparted that it's only 2.84 GB, so what I did is that I used the following command;

```
am@sam:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd
    dd: writing to '/dev/sdd': No space left on device
    5949721+0 records in
    5949720+0 records out
    3046256640 bytes (3.0 GB, 2.8 GiB) copied, 12.8159 s, 238 MB/s
    sam@sam:~$
```

But I still have the same problem.

Comment: What was the problem that made you overwrite the USB stick? Have you been using more than 3 GB  before the problem started? There could be a hardware failure but also a fake drive (containing a smaller memory than specified). You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: It seems like I'm unlucky, but I'm still trying

Comment: the problem was that I was installing a full ubuntu on the USB but an error has occurred while installation saying something like "failed to create file system.." so what I did is that I unplugged the USB stick and plugging it again and trying to format it.

Comment: at this moment the error has occurred

Comment: It is possible that the drive contains only 3 GB of memory, and that is not enough to install Ubuntu. Some USB sticks and memory cards are sold with false labels. It is also possible that some memory cell or electronic circuit is damaged. -- Have you checked if the drive really is wiped, that you can see it as a drive without any partition table? And can you use gparted to create a partition table and a partition and use it (within 3 GB)?

Comment: No I don't think that this is the problem because I have been using this USB for a long time, I remember that in the past I have installed also tails on it and it was running perfectly

Comment: Maybe Tails is small enough to fit within 3 GB?

Comment: there is something really weird, I have also tried to do the same thing above on another usb stick but this time the usb stick is 12GB and the same problem is showing to me, after using the command dd it's showing me the same result!

Comment: result: 3046256640 bytes (3.0 GB, 2.8 GiB) copied, 14.8266 s, 205 MB/s

Comment: Yes I think that tails is smaller than 3 GB, Do you think that this problem is happening because I should reboot the device? I'll try and come back again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106794/discussion-between-sudodus-and-sam-islam).